# Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block on new M2 ssd, can't be failing, right?

Tags: ssd, drive, fsck, read-only, dmesg

It's new M2 nvme samsung 951p ssd that has been going into read only mode few days per day last several days.
Im fighting the issue ever since and seems to be narrowing down to this:

```
 Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block on
```

here is the full dmesg

```
[  260.441694] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 809999
[  260.441700] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810000
[  260.441702] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810001
[  260.441705] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810002
[  260.441706] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810003
[  260.441709] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810004
[  260.441710] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810005
[  260.441712] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 810006
[  260.448591] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.448594] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001087ec])
[  260.448726] loop: Write error at byte offset 4437360640, length 4096.
[  260.448729] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8666720
[  260.448733] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262458 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1083341)
[  260.448734] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 1083340
[  260.566164] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.566169] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000002fec5a])
[  260.566320] loop: Write error at byte offset 12864167936, length 4096.
[  260.566324] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 25125328
[  260.566328] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 393227 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 3140667)
[  260.566329] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 3140666
[  260.570268] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.570272] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000108857])
[  260.570425] loop: Write error at byte offset 4437798912, length 4096.
[  260.570428] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8667576
[  260.570432] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262393 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1083448)
[  260.592133] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.592137] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000108858])
[  260.592290] loop: Write error at byte offset 4437803008, length 4096.
[  260.592295] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8667584
[  260.592299] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262458 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1083449)
[  260.601794] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.601798] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000108c04])
[  260.601936] loop: Write error at byte offset 4441653248, length 4096.
[  260.601940] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8675104
[  260.601944] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262393 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1084389)
[  260.738779] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.738788] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000015d641])
[  260.738920] loop: Write error at byte offset 5861675008, length 4096.
[  260.738925] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 11448584
[  260.738929] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 263498 (offset 0 size 32768 starting block 1431081)
[  260.751649] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.751653] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000010af7a])
[  260.751807] loop: Write error at byte offset 4478836736, length 4096.
[  260.751810] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8747728
[  260.751814] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262359 (offset 0 size 8192 starting block 1093468)
[  260.760637] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.760642] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001095af])
[  260.761022] loop: Write error at byte offset 4451790848, length 4096.
[  260.761026] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8694904
[  260.761030] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262327 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1086864)
[  260.768584] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.768588] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001097ac])
[  260.769048] loop: Write error at byte offset 4453875712, length 4096.
[  260.769052] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8698976
[  260.769056] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262393 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1087373)
[  260.769203] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.769205] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000015d649])
[  260.784773] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.784782] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000029ee17])
[  260.785280] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.785284] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000c5c37])
[  260.790484] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.790487] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000264520])
[  260.790662] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.790665] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000029822f])
[  260.790774] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.790777] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000029824e])
[  260.790987] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.790989] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000015d650])
[  260.793026] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  260.793029] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000015d658])
[  261.303908] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  261.303914] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000020804d])
[  261.484511] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  261.484516] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000219])
[  263.299929] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  263.299933] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000307195])
[  265.859964] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.859969] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884dd])
[  265.860073] lo_write_bvec: 10 callbacks suppressed
[  265.860074] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581637120, length 4096.
[  265.860076] blk_update_request: 10 callbacks suppressed
[  265.860077] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854760
[  265.860123] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860125] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884de])
[  265.860177] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581641216, length 4096.
[  265.860179] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854768
[  265.860229] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860231] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884df])
[  265.860277] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581645312, length 4096.
[  265.860279] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854776
[  265.860325] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860327] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e0])
[  265.860371] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581649408, length 4096.
[  265.860373] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854784
[  265.860429] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860435] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e1])
[  265.860501] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581653504, length 4096.
[  265.860503] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854792
[  265.860548] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860550] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e2])
[  265.860602] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581657600, length 4096.
[  265.860603] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854800
[  265.860644] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860646] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e3])
[  265.860696] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581661696, length 4096.
[  265.860698] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854808
[  265.860748] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860750] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e4])
[  265.860806] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581665792, length 4096.
[  265.860807] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854816
[  265.860861] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860862] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e5])
[  265.860912] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581669888, length 4096.
[  265.860914] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854824
[  265.860965] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.860967] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e6])
[  265.861015] loop: Write error at byte offset 6581673984, length 4096.
[  265.861017] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12854832
[  265.861066] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861068] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e7])
[  265.861168] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861169] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e8])
[  265.861264] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861266] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884e9])
[  265.861377] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861379] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ea])
[  265.861479] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861480] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884eb])
[  265.861578] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.861579] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ec])
[  265.862309] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862314] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ed])
[  265.862431] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862433] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ee])
[  265.862530] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862532] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ef])
[  265.862620] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862622] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f0])
[  265.862725] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862727] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f1])
[  265.862823] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862824] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f2])
[  265.862921] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.862923] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f3])
[  265.863008] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863009] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f4])
[  265.863093] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863095] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f5])
[  265.863185] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863187] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f6])
[  265.863277] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863278] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f7])
[  265.863364] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863366] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f8])
[  265.863453] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863455] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884f9])
[  265.863537] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863539] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884fa])
[  265.863628] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863630] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884fb])
[  265.863752] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.863754] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884fc])
[  265.863840] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on loop0-8
[  265.864024] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864026] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884fd])
[  265.864131] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864132] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884fe])
[  265.864227] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864229] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001884ff])
[  265.864325] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864328] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000188500])
[  265.864438] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864441] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000188501])
[  265.864531] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864533] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000188502])
[  265.864597] Aborting journal on device loop0-8.
[  265.864645] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  265.864647] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000188361])
[  265.864697] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1606465, lost sync page write
[  265.864702] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for loop0-8.
[  266.548339] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  266.548343] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000020])
[  266.548451] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  266.548458] EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[  266.548460] EXT4-fs (loop0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  266.548462] EXT4-fs (loop0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[  266.548539] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  266.548541] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000020])
[  266.548598] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  270.211948] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  270.211959] ecryptfs_writepage: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000004])
[  273.540143] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.540150] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000100048])
[  273.540366] lo_write_bvec: 31 callbacks suppressed
[  273.540369] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295131136, length 4096.
[  273.540374] blk_update_request: 34 callbacks suppressed
[  273.540376] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8388928
[  273.540381] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048616, lost async page write
[  273.540576] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.540584] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000100093])
[  273.540838] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295438336, length 4096.
[  273.540845] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8389528
[  273.540849] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048691, lost async page write
[  273.540984] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.540989] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001000fb])
[  273.541162] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295864320, length 4096.
[  273.541168] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8390360
[  273.541172] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048795, lost async page write
[  273.541290] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.541294] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000180020])
[  273.541415] loop: Write error at byte offset 6442450944, length 4096.
[  273.541418] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12582912
[  273.541421] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1572864, lost async page write
[  273.541503] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.541505] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018008d])
[  273.541582] loop: Write error at byte offset 6442897408, length 4096.
[  273.541585] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12583784
[  273.541587] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1572973, lost async page write
[  273.541675] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.541677] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000182333])
[  273.541750] loop: Write error at byte offset 6479228928, length 4096.
[  273.541753] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12654744
[  273.541755] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1581843, lost async page write
[  273.541848] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.541853] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000020005e])
[  273.541973] loop: Write error at byte offset 8590188544, length 4096.
[  273.541975] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 16777712
[  273.541977] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 2097214, lost async page write
[  273.542040] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.542043] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000202181])
[  273.542127] loop: Write error at byte offset 8624934912, length 4096.
[  273.542131] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 16845576
[  273.542133] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 2105697, lost async page write
[  273.542211] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.542213] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000280023])
[  273.542286] loop: Write error at byte offset 10737430528, length 4096.
[  273.542289] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 20971544
[  273.542291] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 2621443, lost async page write
[  273.542348] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  273.542351] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000280029])
[  273.542419] loop: Write error at byte offset 10737455104, length 4096.
[  273.542422] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 20971592
[  273.542424] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 2621449, lost async page write
[  300.931574] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[  300.931593] ecryptfs_writepage: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000005])
```

Can't be failing right? Or can it?

reboot and fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root fixes it for a while
finds 0.6% errors and fixes them, orphans, inodes and such.

start to happen more and more often!

It's latest Ubuntu with full disk encryption and then home dir encryption. Might be that?

Comment: Could be an intermittent hardware problem - the SSD's connector not being snugly attached to the machine's connector.

Comment: If it was that Jos I believe, reboot and fsck wouldn't be immediatelly fixing it.